# How do you get MVP in MAG?

Tags: mag

I have clocked up over 140 hours in MAG and rarely get less than a 3-1 kill/death ratio. Despite this, I have only ever got third Most Valuable Player on one occasion. Can someone give me some pointers on how to top the MVP.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

MVP is awarded to the player with the most experience (before the bonus XP that is rewarded at the end) in the game. Some ways to boost your XP include:

- Reviving your teammates often (+10 per revive)
- Become a veteran (+10% XP per game)
- Deploy through directives (+10% XP per game)
- Destroy vehicles
- Stay in FRAGO areas as often as possible
- Blow up items that are fragged
- Repair when you can
- Be the SL/PL
- And of course, netting kills